# Host meta and chat.meta on separate server

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Looks like there are some problems right now.

I'm wondering whether it wouldn't be good for meta and chat.meta to **(EDIT: continue to)** be hosted in a different place, so that we can get updates even while the rest is down?

Comment: OK, back up now, but the question remains...

Comment: So less than 40 seconds of downtime?  I dunno that it's necessary, given the fact that downtime over the last two years has been very low.  We've only had one outage that I'm aware of that lasted more than and hour or so.

Comment: @Pollyanna, down again :) As Marc (I'm guessing) says "Server did something.. interesting. I don't like interesting :("

Comment: @Marc Stop poking the poor hamster! It'll stop falling off the wheel if you do that!

Comment: Well, were working on it...

Comment: Oh, by the way: I don't understand the question. As you see, meta is up :)

Comment: Of course there's always the added risk that ALL of the combined users of SO, SU, SF and SE pile onto meta to see what's happening and take *that* down too :)

Answer (score 1):

Umm .. they are already. chat.meat is hosted in OR and meta.so is hosted in NY.

Comment: Yeah, but: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/datacenter-migration-oct-23/

Comment: "chat.meat" is cute :)

Comment: @balpha it is dead right now ... and trains are bouncy :) oh and shouldn't you be umm fixing this ? @Benjol the plan right now is to leave chat.* in OR

Comment: where did you read tha... OK, I read your profile :)

Answer (score 1):

Of course, this is a moot question if it's the *chat* that's bringing the servers down! ;)

Comment: which was in fact the case. Chat, oddly enough, has a historical habit of killing servers in a way that our core engine never has to my knowledge. I'm just sayin.. :)

Comment: In fairness, I guess the core team doesn't have a virtual bunch of developers standing round proposing 10 new features a second and egging them on with "go on, push it into production, we won't tell!" ;)

Answer (score 1):

completed, because meta and chat.meta are and *have always been* on different servers in a different location. (OR and NY)