# When will the migration be over?

Tags: discussion, meta

On the "Accounts" page, it says (for the past few days?)

> **Account Association Disabled**
>
> While the network is being migrated, account associations to Meta have been disabled.

I can't seem to find answers here or on Google.

Comment: 6-8 weeks. May be days or hours also!

Comment: No more 6-8 weeks, comments, please! (For at least...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most recent [blog entry](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/datacenter-migration-oct-23/) states:

> This Saturday, October 23rd, starting at about 2 PM Pacific, we will be migrating all of our primary sites from the Corvallis, OR datacenter to the New York, NY datacenter.
>
> Please be advised that this is a major move, and while we will do everything we can to prevent major service interruptions (largely with a read-only site mode we’re introducing), **there may be a few hours of unavoidable downtime**.

I would presume that at the completion of this, the migration will be complete.

---

EDIT:  Account association is back. (:

Comment: Thanks, I just discovered and was about to post that from [Vi, Vim, and Vixens](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14187/vi-vim-and-vixens). It looks like the link there must be broken or incomplete, though.

Comment: -1, "we will be migrating all of our __primary sites__ " (emphasis mine) implies to me that the non-primary sites will _not_ be moving, and therefore the migration will _not_ be complete.

Comment: @Popular, it seems like chat is what will be left behind.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68294/host-meta-and-chat-meta-on-separate-unicorn#comment-164116

Comment: @rchern, hm, that's helpful, but it only leaves me wanting more answers. I'll undownvote when possible, though.

Comment: @Popular You only have half an hour, right? Or is it even less? Actually, I think it's pretty short.

Comment: Oh, and @Popular, if they are only migrating the primary sites, doesn't that mean it will be over once those are moved? It just comes down to how you define the word, if that is the case.

Comment: @Mark, it's <11 mins.

Comment: @rchern: Promise to undownvote fulfilled.